# Im using hyperledger fabric, and im receiving a non-zero return code for when i try to run 'run the orderer raft leader election script'

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

Im using hyperledger fabric, and im receiving a non-zero return code for when i try to run 'run the orderer raft leader election script on cli container'

Im using docker to run hyperledger fabric.

if you need any more info please let me know.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpKd2.jpg)